# Flutter clear input form value during Edit

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have an **edit form** contains **input field, dropdown, radio button, date field**. I've displayed all the available values that were used gave input before. I've to `clear` the form if the user gave input some `new value` and thought not to `Edit/Update`. Then user clicked on the `Cancel button`. While clicking on the cancel button I've to `clear the whole page except the saved value that's displayed in the edit form`. I've tried using this

```
final _peopleForm = GlobalKey<FormState>();
_peopleForm.currentState?.reset(); // reset the value
```

But this will clear only the input field. The selected value in the dropdown/radio button/ date field isn't cleared.
How can I clear all the forms by clicking on the *Cancel Button*

Answer (score 0):

It's because your dropdown,  radio button and date field doesn't embed FormField by default.

You could use some package if you want it to be done :

- dropdown_formfield
- radio_button_form_field
- datetime_picker_formfield

Note : sorry i put the first thing I've googled